# Why is parameter i preserved across calls to delegate function in lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have following C# code and I am finding that the value of parameter `i` is carried over to the next call of the lambda expression delegate.

```
string[] arrayOne = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Three", "Three"};

string[] newArray = arrayOne.Where ((string n, int i)=> {return i++ <=2;} ).ToArray();
// newArray is {"One","Two", "Three"}
```

My expectation was that a new parameter `i` would be passed for each call to the delegate. I know that local variables being used in a lambda expression are preserved across all calls due to closures, but this is a parameter.

Question:

Why is the value of parameter `i` being preserved across all calls to the delegate?

Comment: It is not. The `i` is each time another one, but since it is an index, it is incremented *anyway*. If you would use `+= 2`, then you will see that `i` is each time a different one.

Comment: In the first call `i` is 0, the second `i` is 1, and the third `i` is 2, so after the first three `i > 2`. Whether you update `i` or not, has no impact.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks. The operator `i++` is having no effect on value of i for next call, even though ` i` is being incremented within each call of the delegate after the comparison operation. `i` is treated as just a method parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there are two override linq `where`.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate);
```

You call use second parameter `int` type value means your array index.

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Where<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int, bool> predicate);
```

This will return a value in the collection with an index value less or equal than 2.

```
Where ((string n, int i)=> {return i++ <=2;})
```

but the `i++` makes no sense because you leave delegate function scope,The value of auto increment i does not remain

Answer (score 2):

> My expectation was that a new parameter I would be passed for each call to the delegate. I know that local variables being used in a lambda expression are preserved across all calls due to closures, but this is a parameter.

The parameter is *not* preserved between calls. The second parameter (the `int i`) is however an *index*, and it is thus *incremented* by the logic in the `.Where(..)` function itself.

In the `Where` it looks more or less like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where(this IEnumerable<T> data, Funct<T, int, bool> p) {
    int i = 0;
    foreach(T t in data) {
        if(p(t, i)) {
            yield return t;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

> **Note**: If we inspect the source code, we see that it delegates to the [`WhereIterator`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Where.cs#L60) function, that performs the logic. I hear provided a more "clean" implementation to explain the idea.

Notice the `i++`: the index is incremented *by* the `Where` function. Regardless what is done with the `i` in the function, we each time call it with another value. An `int` is not a *reference* object, so you can not *update* the "state" of the number.

Take for example the following call:

```
csharp> arrayOne.Where ((string n, int i)=> {i += 2; return i <= 4;} )
{ "One", "Two", "Three" }
```

Here we increment `i` with `2`, and we see that indeed indices that are less than `2` (or indices incremented by two are less than `4`) are still the same. So the index does *not* make hops of two or three.